# Relative Navbar in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, next.js13

I am new to nextjs I wish to create a navbar and navigate between screens using file path routing. But I want the navbar position to be static and while clicking on the navbar button I only want the below view to rerender not the navbar. So how can I achieve it in nextjs with file path routing , any help will be appreciated.

Currently I am using next js version of 13.4.19 and use MUI framework for navbar design

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3RQt.png) here is the navbar design
while navigating to a page I am having a view like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt42U.png)

This is my code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bycrr.png)

Comment: Hey you need to share your work, I mean the code you have written so far.

Comment: I have attached the code image above

Answer (score 0):

Since NextJs 13 introduced the app directory, to have your navbar static, you will need to create or import your navbar in the layout.js. Take for example, suppose you want all homepage info to have the same navbar:

create a directory like this:

```
app
 (homepage)
   about
    page.js
  contact
    page.js
  layout.js
  page.js
```

Your navbar goes in the layout.js, so every page in each directory in that (homepage) shares same layout and navbar. Note that with this, your app routing is unaffected.

```
domain/ = loads page.js in the (homepage)/page.js
domain/about = loads page.js in the (homepage)/about/page.js
```

Without the round bracket around the homepage, it will have taken the homepage as a super route, like

```
domain/homepage/about
```

You can read more about it here: [NextJs 13 Route](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13#layouts)